# Disable SQLCipher check on copying sqlite file

Tags: java, sqlite, spring-boot

Copying a sqlite `.db` file from `src/main/resources` to `target` requires `SQLCipher` to open file though original .db file has no encryption protection on.

```
FileUtils.copyFile(new ClassPathResource("file.db").getFile(), new File("target/file.db"));
```

How can this popup that asks for decryption key be disabled while copying .db file ?
Do we need to set some PRAGMA in original file ?

Comment: There's nothing in that code which should trigger a popup for a decryption key.

Comment: That is what is not clear. If original file is already in target location, copy from target to target/{subfolder} happens and no key is asked on opening db file. Its when file is copied from src/main/resources that this issue is faced. [spring boot project]

Answer (score 0):

Replacing Spring's `ClassPathResource` as below does not require popup now on opening file :

```
FileUtils.copyFile(new File("src/main/resources/file.db"), new File("target/file.db"));
```